# Only printing the length of the query string

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with the following connection, I am just trying to insert records into the database, and for some reason, it just keeps on printing the following two things whenever I try to run my program:

```
the length of the Query String for Error is :506
Value of Catch inside Catch with SQLException ex1:true
```

My code is as follows:

```
Statement InsertRemoteResultsErrorLogStmt = null;
ResultSet SelectErrorLogRS = null;
Connection connRemoteforCatch = null;

try {

    String QueryStringInsertIntoErrorLogs = "";

    connRemoteforCatch = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.x.xxx:3306/test", MainUser, MainPass);

    QueryStringInsertIntoErrorLogs = " INSERT INTO simplequeue.errorlogs "
            + " ( "
            + " ErrorNumber_int, "
            + " Created_dt, "
            + " Subject_vch, "
            + " Message_vch, "
            + " TroubleshootingTips_vch, "
            + " CatchType_vch, "
            + " CatchMessage_vch, "
            + " CatchDetail_vch, "
            + " Host_vch, "
            + " Referer_vch, "
            + " UserAgent_vch, "
            + " Path_vch, "
            + " Querystring_vch "
            + " ) "
            + " VALUES "
            + " ( "
            //+ " NULL, "  // ErrorLogIdInt
            + " 2002 , " // ErrorNumber_int
            + " 2014-03-12 14:55:32   , "
            + " SimpleX Error Notification, "
            + " Error Simple X Queue, "
            + " No Troubleshooting Tips Specified, "
            + " testgetsqlstate  , "
            + " testgetmessage ,"
            + " NULL, "
            + " ebmdevii.messagebroadcast.com,"
            + " NULL, "
            + " CFSCHEDULE, "
            + " NULL, "
            + " DBSOURCE=BishopDev, "
            + " ) ";

    System.out.println("the length of the Query String for Error is :" + QueryStringInsertIntoErrorLogs.length());

    InsertRemoteResultsErrorLogStmt = connRemoteforCatch.createStatement();
    InsertRemoteResultsErrorLogStmt.executeUpdate(QueryStringInsertIntoErrorLogs);

} catch (SQLException ex1) {
    System.out.println("Stacktrace below:");
    ex1.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Value of Catch inside Catch with SQLException ex1:" + connRemoteforCatch.isValid(2));

}
```

Here is my Stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace below:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:55:32   ,  SimpleX Error Notification,  Error Simple X Queue,  No Troubleshoo' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at mypackagename.Myclassreader.call(Myclassreader.java:492)
    at mypackagename.Myclassreader.call(Myclassreader.java:25)
```

Although it says SQL syntax error in the very first line, I used the same SQL Query in MySQL Workbench and inserted the records successfully. And there doesn't seems to be any syntax error in my Java program. Please advise

Updated Stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace below:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Error Notification,  Error Simple X Queue,  No Troubleshooting Tips Specified,  ' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

**Most Recent Stacktrace:**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
at ebmextractor.Myclassreader.call(Myclassreader.java:493)
at ebmextractor.Myclassreader.call(Myclassreader.java:25)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1259)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: How about adding the stack trace instead of commenting out, so we can see what the problem is? Comment the print line and uncomment the stack trace and post the result.

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace? uncomment `ex1.printStackTrace();`

Comment: I think you need to read the document on [`Connection#isValid`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) to understand what it is telling you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enquote the values that you are trying to insert in single quotes except for NULL and numerical values.

PROTIP: Use System.out.println to see the final query string and then try running it in MySQL. To reduce the clutter of JDBC error messages.

Comment: You mean I should do something like `System.out.println("Query String:"+QueryStringInsertIntoErrorLogs);` ?

Comment: Nice tip, Because of your tip, I was able to resolve the most recent error. Thanks for additional tip. There was an additional comma after the last column value in my SQL Query.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know MySQL, but presumably your date needs to at least be in quotes - possibly also have a cast attached.

```
           + " '2014-03-12 14:55:32'   , "
```

Edit: Taking a look at [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) I am guessing it could look like:

```
+ " TIMESTAMP '2014-03-12 14:55:32' , "
```

But I don't know the type of the column you're inserting into

Edit 2:

Thanks to Emanual, I'd like to add that you need to quote the other strings in the insert also:

```
QueryStringInsertIntoErrorLogs = " INSERT INTO simplequeue.errorlogs "
        + " ( "
        + " ErrorNumber_int, "
        + " Created_dt, "
        + " Subject_vch, "
        + " Message_vch, "
        + " TroubleshootingTips_vch, "
        + " CatchType_vch, "
        + " CatchMessage_vch, "
        + " CatchDetail_vch, "
        + " Host_vch, "
        + " Referer_vch, "
        + " UserAgent_vch, "
        + " Path_vch, "
        + " Querystring_vch "
        + " ) "
        + " VALUES "
        + " ( "
        //+ " NULL, "  // ErrorLogIdInt
        + " 2002 , " // ErrorNumber_int
        + " '2014-03-12 14:55:32', "
        + " 'SimpleX Error Notification', "
        + " 'Error Simple X Queue', "
        + " 'No Troubleshooting Tips Specified', "
        + " 'testgetsqlstate'  , "
        + " 'testgetmessage' ,"
        + " NULL, "
        + " 'ebmdevii.messagebroadcast.com',"
        + " NULL, "
        + " 'CFSCHEDULE', "
        + " NULL, "
        + " 'DBSOURCE=BishopDev', "
        + " ) ";
```

Comment: Maybe the spaces are causing a problem? I'm no MySql expert, but maybe the jdbc driver is parsing the spaces incorrectly or something?

Comment: Changing date to ` + " '2014-03-12 14:55:32'   , "` has reduced my stacktrace to two lines as shown in my updated post.

Comment: @Jeff - Almost there but the OP should enquote not only the dates but also the other strings that are being inserted.

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan true -  Iwas just looking at the specific thing that was showing the error. I'll update my answer, thanks

Comment: @Jeff Should I include TIMESTAMP as well just like mentioned by you and in the doc?

Comment: @John See if it works without - I expect it will be fine with just the quotes. Otherwise, add it in. Just make sure that if you do put an explicit cast in that it's the data type of the column you're inserting into - if `Created_dt` is a DateTime then cast to that instead of Timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

**The exception is due to the incorrect formation of SQL query**,

Try to put your Strings in the single qoute,

for e.g.

```
+"'ebmdevii.messagebroadcast.com'"+
```